# Как сравнить два текстовых документа скриптом php

Tags: php

Есть текстовый файл "А", в него столбиком записаны числа  и есть другой текстовый файл "В" который создан программой и в котором должны быть такие же значения как в текстовом файле "A". Необходимо сравнить эти два файла и выдать совпадения.

---

Пример:

файл "А":

```
--1.к--
0  200,548
1  201,579
0  202,569
--2.к--
0  200,578
1  201,578
0  202,200
1  203,356
--3.к--
0  100,506
1  105,501
0  110,501
1  115,501
```

файл "В":

```
--1.к--
0  200,512
1  201,500
0  203,515
--3.к--
0  100,506
1  105,501
0  107,526
1  109,325
```

Сценарий:

1. Открытие текстового файла А.txt , чтение строк  учитывая пробелы
2. открытие текстового файла В.txt,  чтение строк
3. Сравнение содержимого в файлах если есть не совпадения выдать результат в виде таблицы с тремя графами: графа "А", графа "В", графа "результат"

Comment: я думаю не помешает добавить перенос строки в своём сообщении, немного не понятно....

Comment: и в чем _ИМЕННО_ у вас проблемы ? А то как задание звучит

Comment: Да и вообще, необходимо уточнить, ведь совпадения могут быть разные

1) Вам нужно что бы выводилось сообщение, если найдено совпадение на строке N в файлах A и B
2) или выводилось тогда, когда совпадает строка N файла A, и строка M файла B

Comment: Вызвать внешнюю утилиту (diff, в виндах --fc) и не заморачиваться этой проблемой

Comment: Смысл заключается в том, что файл "А" является эталонным и по нему сверяется другой файл "В" который создается после обработки определенных задач - программой (серверное приложение). Программа выдает результат работы определенного оборудования в виде числовых значений и мне приходится сравнивать эти значения самому. Та вот просьба моя адресована людям, способным помочь в написании скрипта.

Comment: Это написать, как вызвать `system` с командной строкой `diff -q имя-файла-A имя-файла-B` и проанализировать код возврата (0 -- различий нет, 1 -- есть, 2 -- проблемы при сравнении)?

Comment: А почему нельзя разбить файлы строки на массивы и сравнивать соответствующие элементы?

Comment: @NeonDT, если вы хотите, чтобы весь код написали **за вас**, то вы ошиблись сайтом. Вам больше подойдет биржа фрилансеров.

Answer (score 1):

Считав оба файла сформировать 2 массива с данными, котое проверить в цикле поэлементно, и найдя совпадение, записать из в 3 массив, который потом сохранить в файл (если это необходимо).

Comment: логично. но как научить скрипт видеть пробелы и точно сравнивать каждую строку с эталонной?Напиши пример сценария.